# How to remove active class from navbar links in Bootstrap 3.1?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using one page navigation and I don't know how to remove the active state from the `li` element when I am in that particular section of the page. I have tried using JQuery and CSS and none works for me (from the console it works obviously).

This is what works in the console:

```
$('.nav li').removeClass('active');
```

And in CSS I tried:

```
.nav > li {  
   background: transparent;
}
```

I prefer a JQuery solution as it would be easier just to get rid of the active class instead of styling the element.

Comment: When are you calling the `removeClass` code??

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better!

Comment: did you put your code inside document.ready?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar When the page is loaded (in the console).

Comment: @C-link yes, of course. It does not work there, but it works via the console.

Comment: is there a problem: jQuery:: .nav li  ::css:: .nav > li    ????? please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @C-link in this case, there's no difference between the two :) I don't know why a jsfiddle would be needed? It's just too much work for something like this and people familiar with Bootstrap know exactly what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are multiple listeners for document ready. And your code is getting executed before other handler/handlers which sets the class active again. You can use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent that. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $('.nav li').removeClass('active');//or $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

**Update:**

You can also achieve this using `setInterval()`:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');//remove class active
},1000);
```

Comment: @Loolooii: So you never want class active on page??

Comment: Exactly :) And the reason is because I already changed the style of the navbar a lot and the only thing different is the active state.

Comment: @Loolooii:try the second approach

Answer (score 0):

In your html just don't have the active class on any li when the page loads - Unless you want to have 'home' or something active by default then of course have the active class on the relevant li.

Then when a user clicks on an li try this:

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

The above will remove the active class from whatever li it is on then add it to the one which has been clicked.

Comment: The problem is that Bootstrap adds active class automatically when I use anchor links. And it seems that there's no way I can stop that.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't automatically add anything. You decide what gets added and what doesn't as it's you that's writing the HTML.