# navebarMenu is always highlighted

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `navbarPage`, within that I have three `navbarMenu`. But the first `navbarMenu` i.e, "Help" is always highlighted by default and with that `navbarMenu` `tabpanel` "Manual" is also always highlighted. How to avoid that. The sample code is shown below

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                  (navbarPage("B Version",
                              position = c("fixed-top"),
                              fluid=TRUE,
                              navbarMenu("Help",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Manual",
                                             target="_blank", href="Manual.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Supporte",
                                             target="_blank", href="gpl.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Tutorials",
                                             downloadLink("AbE", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             downloadLink("DiEx", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                           )
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Sample Data",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("AData", " Aff", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CData", " Code", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("IData", " Il", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Stand-Alone Version",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CodeandData", " app", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Stand-alone Manual",
                                             target = "_blank", href= "Stand-alone.pdf")
                                         )
                              )

                  )
                  )
)
)
```

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
})
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

***Edit**

*This part show how it reacts with the answer provided @amrrs* . It shows the data when the cursor is pressed and then again disappears.

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                  tags$script("setInterval(function(){
                              $('.active').removeClass('active');//remove class active
                              },1000);"),
                  (navbarPage("B Version",
                              position = c("fixed-top"),
                              fluid=TRUE,selected = "none",
                              navbarMenu("Help", 
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Manual",
                                             target="_blank", href="Manual.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Supporte",
                                             target="_blank", href="gpl.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Tutorials",
                                             downloadLink("AbE", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             downloadLink("DiEx", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                           )
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Sample Data",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("AData", " Aff", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CData", " Code", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("IData", " Il", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Stand-Alone Version",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CodeandData", " app", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Stand-alone Manual",
                                             target = "_blank", href= "Stand-alone.pdf")
                                         )
                              )


)
),

br(),
br(),



sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    h5("Upload Data Files",style="bold"),
    fileInput("files", 
              "Choose CSV/txt processed files or raw files",
              multiple = "TRUE",
              accept=c('text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values,
                       text/plain', '.csv','.cel','.TXT','.txt'))

                      ),

                    mainPanel(
                      tabsetPanel(id = "MaTabs",
                        tabPanel("Source-data", dataTableOutput("sourced"))
                      )

                    )
                    )))
```

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$sourced <- renderDataTable(mtcars)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082303/how-to-remove-active-class-from-navbar-links-in-bootstrap-3-1) adding a small snippet of js helps it.

Updated Code with hiding active only for nav:

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                  tags$script("setInterval(function(){
                              $('.nav').removeClass('active');//remove class active
                              },1000);"),
                  (navbarPage("B Version",
                              position = c("fixed-top"),
                              fluid=TRUE,selected = "none",
                              navbarMenu("Help", 
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Manual",
                                             target="_blank", href="Manual.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Supporte",
                                             target="_blank", href="gpl.pdf")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Tutorials",
                                             downloadLink("AbE", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             downloadLink("DiEx", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                           )
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Sample Data",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("AData", " Aff", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CData", " Code", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("IData", " Il", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         )
                              ),
                              navbarMenu("Stand-Alone Version",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           downloadLink("CodeandData", " app", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                         ),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           a("Stand-alone Manual",
                                             target = "_blank", href= "Stand-alone.pdf")
                                         )
                              )


)
),

br(),
br(),



sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    h5("Upload Data Files",style="bold"),
    fileInput("files", 
              "Choose CSV/txt processed files or raw files",
              multiple = "TRUE",
              accept=c('text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values,
                       text/plain', '.csv','.cel','.TXT','.txt'))

              ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "MaTabs",
                tabPanel("Source-data", dataTableOutput("sourced"))
    )

  )
)))
```

Comment: I have `tabpanel` to show data, it does not show data if i remove the cursor

Comment: It should disable for only `navbarPage`

Comment: Sorry, Do you mean that the tabpanel shows up only when you keep your cursor on?

Comment: I mean the data on tabpanel is shown only when cursor on

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update the code and also a screenshot of how the tabpanel data is shown?

Comment: @AwaitedOne Meanwhile please check the updated code.

Comment: Kindly check the edit above based on your first answer. The data in tabpanel is shown and disappears

Comment: Thanks, Updated the code now. Please check. I could see the table and also the highlight is gone.

Comment: I use `boostrap.css` and in that it didn't change anything. Without `bootstrap.css` highlight of `navbarMenu` is gone but it has highlighted the first `tabpanel` of each `nabbarMenu`

Comment: I am not using ```bootstrap.css``` and in my case, i don't have the highlight and i also could see the table.

Comment: @AwaitedOne Tried without bootstrap.css? anything worked out?

Comment: What about tabpanel of navbarMenu?  Is not the first highlighted

Answer (score 2):

To remove highlight from first `navbarMenu` you can add an argument `selected = "none"` in `navbarPage` function. To remove highlight from `navbarMenu tabpanel` you can use the following css:

`tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .active a{color : #333; background-color:#f5f5f5;}")`

So in your code it would be something like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                             tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .active a{color : #333; background-color:#f5f5f5;}"),

                            (navbarPage("B Version",
                                        position = c("fixed-top"),
                                        fluid=TRUE,selected = "none",
                                        navbarMenu("Help", 
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     a("Manual",
                                                       target="_blank", href="Manual.pdf")
                                                   ),
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     a("Supporte",
                                                       target="_blank", href="gpl.pdf")
                                                   ),
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     a("Tutorials",
                                                       downloadLink("AbE", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                                       downloadLink("DiEx", "Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                                     )
                                                   )
                                        ),
                                        navbarMenu("Sample Data",
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     downloadLink("AData", " Aff", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                                   ),
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     downloadLink("CData", " Code", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                                   ),
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     downloadLink("IData", " Il", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                                   )
                                        ),
                                        navbarMenu("Stand-Alone Version",
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     downloadLink("CodeandData", " app", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                                   ),
                                                   tabPanel(
                                                     a("Stand-alone Manual",
                                                       target = "_blank", href= "Stand-alone.pdf")
                                                   )
                                        )

                            )
                            )
    )
    )
```

With this you get the output as:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. It get  more horrible 1) For `Help` highlight goes off, but for `navebarMenu`, it turns Gray and does not look good at all.

Comment: So, you do not want the `navbarMenu` to be highlighted even when its clicked?

Comment: I want `navbarMenu` to be highlighted too, but in your code, the first `tabpanel` of each `navbarMenu` is turned Gray, while others are same colour. Edit: I have bootstrap also `bootstrap.css` which is not included in the code.

Comment: In my case as shown in the screenshots all of the `tabpanel` are of the same color (black).

Comment: And the first `tabpanel` of each `navbarMenu` remains highlighted always.